# R (base): Adding points with confidence levels to existing plot

Tags: r, plot, graphics, figure

I have a plot with R base:

```
plot(c(1,2), c(2,3), type="l")
points(c(1.2), c(2.2))
```

I now want to add a new data set to this plot that includes confidence levels. Here is how I would plot it:

```
library("plotrix")
set.seed(0815)
x <- 1:2
F <- runif(2,1,2) 
L <- runif(2,0,1)
U <- runif(2,2,3)
plotCI(x, F, ui=U, li=L)
```

But this creates a new plot, it doesn't add it to the first plot I made. Is it possible to combine them in one, single graph?

Comment: You can set the `add=` argument in `plotCI()` to be `TRUE`. But you need to adjust the `xlim=` and `ylim=` first in the `plot()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot` and `plotCI` both automatically create whole new plots. You could use `lines` instead of `plot` and change the order:

```r
library("plotrix")
set.seed(0815)
x <- 1:2
F <- runif(2,1,2) 
L <- runif(2,0,1)
U <- runif(2,2,3)

plotCI(x, F, ui=U, li=L)
lines(c(1,2), c(2,3), type="l")
points(c(1.2), c(2.2))
```

[image]